# How to do connection pooling for Google Cloud Bigtable

Tags: java, java-8, hbase, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

Is there any built-in library exists or is it required to implement custom one?

I have tried to check here, but not sure how to ahead from here: [Bigtable connection pool](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-client/javadoc/com/google/cloud/bigtable/grpc/io/ChannelPool#ChannelPool-com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.io.ChannelPool.ChannelFactory-int-)

I have tried the below code, but not really sure how to progress from here:

```java
import com.google.cloud.bigtable.config.BigtableOptions;
import com.google.cloud.bigtable.config.CredentialOptions;
import com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.BigtableSession;
import com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.io.ChannelPool;
import com.mahindra.digisense.config.AppConfig;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;

@Component
public class BigTableConnectionPoolingExample {

    @Autowired
    private AppConfig.BigTableConfig bigTableConfig;

    private void bigTableConnectionPooling() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        CredentialOptions credentialOptions = CredentialOptions.jsonCredentials(new FileInputStream(new File(bigTableConfig.getCredentialsJson())));
        BigtableOptions.Builder builder = new BigtableOptions.Builder();
        builder.setCredentialOptions(credentialOptions);
        ChannelPool.ChannelFactory channelFactory = (ChannelPool.ChannelFactory) BigtableSession.createChannelPool(bigTableConfig.getInstanceId(), builder.build());
        ChannelPool channelPool = new ChannelPool(channelFactory,3);
    }
}
```

Here is [another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45184510/google-cloud-bigtable-client-connection-pooling), which has no answers.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything related to `ChannelPools`. You also probably shouldn't be using `BigtableSession` directly either.  If you don't want to use the HBase client, I would suggest using https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-bigtable. If you do want to use `BigtableSession`, please raise an issue on https://github.com/googleapis/cloud-bigtable-client, and we can discuss your needs there.

Comment: Ok - thank you for link. I will have a look at it.

Comment: @SolomonDuskis, I ended up using https://github.com/googleapis/cloud-bigtable-client than https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-bigtable as it is mentioned that it is not production ready..

Comment: But I am not clear, if I need to create pool of  `com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.BigtableDataClient` or one object to be used or create one for every request and close at the end.

Comment: We will be changing the documentation on https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-bigtable soon to say that it's production ready.  We will be getting rid of `com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.BigtableDataClient` soon.

If you want to use `com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.BigtableDataClient`, please do so by creating a single `BigtableSession` and calling `getDataClient()`.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Solomon Duskis, we are encouraging new folks to get started with the idiomatic Bigtable client in [google-cloud-java](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-bigtable). The client is suitable for production use, however we have not finalized the client API so we may make backward-incompatible changes.

If you are using the HBase client from the [Cloud Bigtable Client](https://github.com/googleapis/cloud-bigtable-client/) repo, there are options to adjust the number of data channels used underneath as well as the number of inflight RPCs per channel. But we suggest that you profile your application first, as you should be able to achieve good performance and saturate your clusters without needing to manually adjust these parameters from their defaults.