# BigTable initialization in NodeJs backend miroservice

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, backend, google-cloud-bigtable

I am using BigTable in a typical NodeJs Javascript backend application. I'd like to get clarity on how to setup BigTable in a case where we need to make requests through BigTable from different files which contain handler functions.

To put this simply, let's assume a NodeJs server backend with the following simplified file structure :

```
src
|__handlers
  |__file1.js // needs to communicate with BigTable instance A for insert operation
  |__file2.js // needs to communicate with BigTable instance A for delete operation
|__bigtable
   |__index.js // where bigtable is initialized and where bigtable operations are performed.
|__index.js //boostrapping the server application here. This file executes before all others.
|__ config.js // service configuration file
```

What would be the recommendation if we need to call BigTable from multiple places (file1, file2) ?

**- option A) Call new BigTable() once, when bootstrapping the service.**

bigtable/index.js

```js
const config = require('./config')
class BigTableClient { 
  constructor() {
    this.bigTable = new BigTable(config)
    const instance = bigTable.instance(...)
    this.table = instance.table(...)
    ...
 }

module.exports = new BigTableClient()
```

src/index.js

```js
const BigTableClient = require('bigtable/index.js') 
// This will call new BigTableClient() only once due to the caching nature of NodeJs
```

src/handlers/file1 (or 2).js

```js
const BigTableClient = require('bigtable/index.js') 
// This will not re-execute the constructor because it was already called previously in src/index.js. It will just re-use the BigTable singleton instance.
```

**- option B) Calling `new BigTable()` whenever we need to make the communication.**

src/bigtable/index.js

```js
module.exports = { BigTableClient }
```

src/index.js

```js
  const config = require('./config');
  const BTClient = new BigTableClient(config);
```

src/handlers/file1 (or 2).js

```js
  const config = require('./config');
  const BTClient = new BigTableClient(config);
  // not sure if this will re-execute the constructor every time the new is executed here or just use the caching layer of nodeJs
```

**- option C) export a function**

src/bigtable/index.js

```js
  module.exports = (options) => new BigTableClient(options)
  // I think this will re-execute the constructor every time this is called
```

src/index.j, src/handlers/file1 (or 2).js

```js
  const BTClient = require('./bigtable/index.js')(options)
  // it seems this would reexecute the constructor and create a new instance of the client every time, thus maximizing the number of connections
```

I am trying to understand the implications of those different options. More specifically, does it matter if `new BigTable()` is being called multiple times in a single application ? And how does the caching mechanism of NodeJs will affect this behaviour.

Comment: A more appropriate forum to ask how this library should be used would be on the Github [repository](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigtable) for the Node.js BigTable client. Otherwise, you can also reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45184510/) similar question.

Comment: I did ask a while ago https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigtable/issues/1190 but did not get any replies yet. Otherwise, your other question seems to point out that indeed, we need to use this as a singleton with one connection only. On my side, I'd like to clarify a bit more the reasoning around this answer.